# Trying to use blocks in Jade, for Express. Getting "Max Stack Size Exceeded" and setHeader errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using Express, with a simple express-generator made server. The first step I wanted to do was work on making the view layout, and as I'm trying to extend the index page. But I can't do it.

I've had many errors, including that I'm setting my header after . I guess this is a async problem, because it's constantly streaming the header but it has already set a header so that is overwhelming. So, I can't find out where the fatal issue is.

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
    include secondjade
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content

  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  block more

  script.
    console.log("First page loaded")
```

secondjade.jade

```
extends index

block more
    p Columbus
```

ERROR:

```
RangeError: /Users/jeanineotter/development/map_app_1/views/secondjade.jade:5
   3| block more
   4| 
 > 5| p Columbus

/Users/jeanineotter/development/map_app_1/views/secondjade.jade:5
   3| block more
   4| 
 > 5| p Columbus

/Users/jeanineotter/development/map_app_1/views/secondjade.jade:5
   3| block more
   4| 
 > 5| p Columbus

Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Your three jade files are mutually recursive. When you attempt to render the index, it extends layout, which includes secondjade, which extends index, and there the loop begins again.

It seems that you were attempting to include the content of secondjade in the more block of index. To accomplish that, remove the `include secondjade` line from layout, and replace `block more` in index with `include secondjade`.

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content

  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  include secondjade

  script.
    console.log("First page loaded")
```

secondjade.jade

```
block more
    p Columbus
```